# Configuration of Liferay logging system for logs from external library which use slf4j

Tags: log4j, liferay, slf4j, sshj

I'm using library sshj. This library use slf4j for logs, but Liferay based on log4j. 
How to configure Liferay project for print logs from sshj.

EDIT:
My problem is not a slf4j in my liferay portlet. But library, which I'm using, working on slf4j. So, after few atempts, I have logs from ssh, but it is only info level logs, but I need debug level logs. When I try change logs level in liferay interfaces, it's not working.

Comment: if your question asks about using slf4j in liferay .. there is a bridge . . https://web.liferay.com/de/web/denis-signoretto/blog/-/blogs/using-slf4j-and-liferay-logging-framework-in-custom-plugins . but I don't know whether this helps using sshj

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've tried this method, but it's not work. As result I have only info logs, and i can not change logs level for this library

Comment: liferay logging can be configured in the system adminstration section panel of your portal , but if you see info logs , you probably already did that , thats strange... , what about logging config ?

Comment: I can print info logs, but only in Jboss console. And it that case, I found solution which is enougth for me. So, I've created a logger, for specific package, in Jboss console with debug level. As result I have debug logs from sshj in jboss console/file.